# Invariant Violation: renderComponentToString(): You must pass a valid ReactComponent

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to build an application using React and Node.js, but I'm not sure how to use React on the frontend. I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-real-time-twitter-stream-with-node-and-react-js). Right now, in my routes.js file, I have:

```
var JSX = require('node-jsx').install();
var React = require('react');
var Homepage = require('./../components/Homepage');

module.exports = {

    index: function(req, res) {
        var markup = React.renderComponentToString(Homepage);

        res.render('home', {
            markup: markup
        });
    }

};
```

The renderComponentToString method seems to be the problem, since my server starts, then I receive the error message "Error: Invariant Violation: renderComponentToString(): You must pass a valid ReactComponent." My Homepage component looks like:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var React = require('react');
var style = require('./style');

module.exports = About = React.createClass({
    render: function() {

        return (
            <div style={ style.style1 }>
                some more code here
            </div>
        )

    }
})
```

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with my react component. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @MayankShukla: `./../components/Homepage` is the same as `../components/Homepage`.

Comment: The path is strange because I actually have a routes folder containing two different routes files. I'm in route file #1 right now, so I'm just trickling up to the parent directory to access the component folder.

Comment: `Homepage` is a function. I assume `renderComponentToString` actually expects an element: `React.renderComponentToString(<Homepage />);` (or  `React.renderComponentToString(React.createElement(Homepage));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React.renderComponentToString takes a React component. Try passing it like

```
var markup = React.renderComponentToString(Homepage());
```

Refer **[this](http://www.crmarsh.com/react-ssr/)** link